# perl - best way to create gzipped files

Tags: perl

I need to alter my routine and have the final outfile be gzipped. I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to gzip a processed file called within a perl subroutine.

For example, I have a sub routine that creates the file (extract_data). 
Here's the main loop and sub routine:

```
foreach my $tblist (@tblist)
{
   chomp $tblist;
   extract_data($dbh, $tblist);
};
$dbh->disconnect;

sub extract_data
{
     my($dbh, $tblist) = @_;
     my $final_file = "/home/proc/$node-$tblist.dat";
     open (my $out_fh, '>', $final_file) or die "cannot create $final_file: $!";
     my $sth = $dbh->prepare("...");
     $sth->execute();
     while (my($uid, $hostnm,$col1,$col2,$col3,$upd,$col5) = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
       print $out_fh "__my_key__^A$uid^Ehost^A$hostnm^Ecol1^A$col1^Ecol2^A$col2^Ecol3^A$col3^Ecol4^A$upd^Ecol5^A$col5^D";
     }
     $sth->finish;
     close $out_fh or die "Failed to close file: $!";
};
```

Do I do the gzip within the main or with the sub? What is the best way to do so?
Then my new file would be `$final_file =/home/proc/$node-$tblist.dat.gz`

thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know there are modules to do this without using external programs, but since I understand how to use `gzip` a lot better than I understand how to use those modules, I just open a process to `gzip` and call it a day.

```
open (my $gzip_fh, "| /bin/gzip -c > $final_file.gz") or die "error starting gzip $!";
...
while (... = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    print $gzip_fh "__my_key__^A$uid^Ehost^A$hostname..."; # uncompressed data
}
...
close $gzip_fh;
```

Comment: it doesn't get much easier than that

Comment: in my case, what would be `@some_uncompressed_data`? would it be `print $gzip @final_file`?

Comment: @jdamae - it's whatever you are currently sending to `$out_fh`. You can call `print $gzip_fh ...` several times if you want, as you are doing now.

Comment: @Nathan Fellman: yes it does get easier...`use PerlIO::gzip; open( my $gzip_fh, '>:gzip', "$final_file.gz" )`

Comment: @mob How do you specify the encoding of the content being piped to gzip this way.  Somewhat confused where to place something like `:encoding(utf8)` in that `open` statement?

Comment: You can call `binmode $gzip_fh, ":encoding(utf8)"` immediately after the `open`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use IO::Compress::Gzip, which is in the set of core Perl modules:

```
use IO::Compress::Gzip qw(gzip $GzipError) ;

my $z = new IO::Compress::Gzip($fileName);
  or die "gzip failed: $GzipError\n";

# object interface
$z->print($string);
$z->printf($format, $string);
$z->write($string);
$z->close();

# IO::File mode
print($z $string);
printf($z $format, $string);
close($z);
```

More details at [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Compress/Gzip.html)

FWIW, there's also [IO::Uncompress::Gunzip](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.html) for reading from gzipped files in a similar fashion.