# Is there a way to compress a set of files that match a regex using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, zip

I would like to organize some files within a directory.

There is a pattern within the filenames I would like to organize them by, and I have been able to save filenames by this motif using regex.

I'm wondering if I can take it one step further and compress these files into zip files via a Perl script?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = "/home/user/Desktop/";
opendir DIR, $dir or die "cannot open dir $dir: $!";
my @file = readdir DIR;
closedir DIR;

my @files_to_compress;
my $counter = 0;

foreach my $dir_file (@file) {
  if ($dir_file =~ m/(^regex.*\.txt$)/) {
    #Save filenames
    $files_to_compress[$counter] = $dir_file;
    $counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you currently using to compress the files? If it's gzip or anything like it, [this thread might come in handy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173503/perl-best-way-to-create-gzipped-files).

Comment: I need to create .zip files.

Comment: Here's a module for zip archives: http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Archive-Zip-1.33/lib/Archive/Zip.pm

Comment: I think you need to explain better what it is that you want to do. Are you trying to replace a directory with an equivalent zip file, or do you just want to create a zip library of all `regex...txt` files in a given directory. You should note that your regex matches anything starting `regex.tx`, followed by an optional `t`, and anything after that, so `regexaaaaaaa.tx.a.a.01` would match just fine.

Comment: @Borodin, that `?` should be a `$`. Thanks for catching that.

As for what I want to do, I want to get all regex..txt files and add them to a zip file. This will not replace the already existing directory/organizational structure. I just need to compress these files for transfer.

Comment: Sorry, no, that's impossible. File compression is a pipe dream...

Comment: Or alternately: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my @files_to_compress;
my $counter=0;
foreach my $dir_file(@file){
if($dir_file =~ m/(^regex.*\.txt?)/){
          #Save filenames
          $files_to_compress[$counter]=$dir_file;
          $counter++;
    }
}
```

Is usually written in Perl in this way:

```
my @files_to_compress = grep m/^regex.*\.txt$/, @file;
```

And you will create Zip archive this way.

```
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES );
my $dir = "/home/user/Desktop/";
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
opendir my $dh, $dir or die "cannot open dir $dir: $!";
$zip->addFile(grep m/^regex.*\.txt$/, readdir $dh);
$zip->writeToFileNamed('someZip.zip') == AZ_OK or die 'write error';
```

But far simpler will be

```
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES );
my $dir = "/home/user/Desktop/";
my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();
$zip->addFile(<$dir/regex*.txt>);
$zip->writeToFileNamed('someZip.zip') == AZ_OK or die 'write error';
```

Comment: This is not an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion for doing it without involving Perl, which is IMHO overkill for this:

```
find /home/user/Desktop/ -regex '.*/regex.*\.txt' -print | xargs zip archive.zip
```

Comment: So you think the OP's regex `^regex.*\.txt?` is irrelevant? The OP asked for a Perl solution.

Comment: No, I don't think it's irrelevant; why do you say that?

Comment: Because your `find` command does something very different. See my comment on the original question.

Comment: I can't help you because I can't understand how you can think it is the same. All I can suggest is that you experiment and work on your Perl regular expressions.

Comment: Well, if you can give an example of a case where my solution would generate a different result, it would help me understand why we're seeing it differently. If you don't want to, of course that's fine. All I can say is that I think this would help solve the OP's problem, and I hope they find it useful.

Comment: On the other hand, if `zip archive.zip regex*.txt` is all the OP really needs, why replace it with dozens of lines of Perl? (Learning is a fair answer, but if that's not the goal?)

Comment: The OP had a [typo in their regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227795/is-there-a-way-to-compress-a-set-of-files-that-match-a-regex-using-perl#comment30167851_20227795). This solution did not work for the regex as originally posted, hence @Borodin's comments.

Answer (score 0):

You said, *"...compress these files into zip files via a Perl script..."*  If I understand you correctly, you want a zip file for each `regex*.txt` file.  If this is the case, using the module [Archive::Zip](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Archive-Zip-1.33/lib/Archive/Zip.pm) and `glob` (`<>`) may be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES );

my $dir = '/home/user/Desktop';

for (<$dir/regex*.txt>) {
    my $zip     = Archive::Zip->new();
    my $zipFile = $zip->addFile($_);
    $zip->writeToFileNamed( $_ . '.zip' ) == AZ_OK or die "Unable to save file $_.zip\n";
}
```